# Десктопная версия сайта на мобильных

Tags: html, css

Подскажите как можно сделать так чтобы сайт на мобильном устройстве отображался точно так же как и на десктопной версии (то есть абсолютно то же самое, только уменьшенный вариант).

meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width - удалил в теге все кроме этого и на андроиде все выглядит нормально. но на айфонах (проблема не в мобильном сафари) все равно появляется горизонтальный скролл.

Сайт никак не адаптирован и необходимо чтобы в мобильной версии отображался именно десктопная версия.

Comment: Вы ставили `overflow: hidden` для `body`?

Comment: @highpassion, да, ставил. Во viewport поставил initial-scale=0. Я так понял это максимально отдаляет сайт при инициализации. И опять, на андроиде все нормально, а на айфонах не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение

```js
if (window.devicePixelRatio !== 1) {    
      var dpt = window.devicePixelRatio;
      var widthM = window.screen.width * dpt;
      var widthH = window.screen.height * dpt;
      document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="width=' + widthM+ ', height=' + widthH + '">');  
}
```